# Reshape data frame in R with id, time and one column with several data variables

Tags: r, reshape

I did not find anything specifying how to reshape a data frame with a time column, an id column and a column with several variables which I want to have in different columns.

If only two categories are needed, its trivial:

[How to reshape data from long to wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format-r)

[Reshaping data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533493/reshaping-data-frame-in-r)

However, I have:

```
geo    time    indic_na    value
AT    2014Q1    B11        2556
BE    2014Q1    B11        1506.0
...   ...       ...        ...
AT    2014Q1    B1G        72065.1
```

and I want:

```
geo    time    B11       B1G       ...
AT     2014Q1  2556      72065.1   ...
AT     2013Q4  2535.4    ...
...    ...     ...       ...       ...
BE     2014Q1  1506.0    86513.0   ...
```

so I want every unique string in indic_na to become one column variable. To get the data:

```
install.packages("SmarterPoland")
library(zoo)
library(SmarterPoland)
GDP <- getEurostatRCV(kod = "namq_gdp_c")
GDP$time = as.yearqtr(GDP$time)
GDP <- subset(GDP, (s_adj == "SWDA") & (unit == "MIO_EUR") & (time > "1989Q4"))
```

And then I tried:

```
testvector <- as.vector(unique(GDP$indic_na))
test <- reshape(data = GDP, direction = "long", idvar = "geo", timevar = "time", varying = testvector)
```

amongst maaany other things for "varying" ;-) I get this error message:

> Error in guess(varying) :
>
> failed to guess time-varying variables from their names

I feel so close! But somehow I can't tell R that the variables are in the 3rd column of my data frame. All examples which I find online already have the different variables in different columns or only have id OR time and a column of variables.

Any help would be great!

#### Easily reproducible data

```
> dput(head(GDP))
structure(list(geo = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Names = c("SWDA,MIO_EUR,B11,AT", 
"SWDA,MIO_EUR,B11,BE", "SWDA,MIO_EUR,B11,BG", "SWDA,MIO_EUR,B11,CH", 
"SWDA,MIO_EUR,B11,CY", "SWDA,MIO_EUR,B11,CZ"), .Label = c("AT", 
"BA", "BE", "BG", "CH", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "EA", "EA12", 
"EA17", "EA18", "EE", "EL", "ES", "EU15", "EU27", "EU28", "FI", 
"FR", "HR", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "JP", "LT", "LU", "LV", "ME", 
"MK", "MT", "NL", "NO", "PL", "PT", "RO", "RS", "SE", "SI", "SK", 
"TR", "UK", "US"), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014), class = "yearqtr"), indic_na = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Names = c("SWDA,MIO_EUR,B11,AT", "SWDA,MIO_EUR,B11,BE", 
"SWDA,MIO_EUR,B11,BG", "SWDA,MIO_EUR,B11,CH", "SWDA,MIO_EUR,B11,CY", 
"SWDA,MIO_EUR,B11,CZ"), .Label = c("B11", "B111", "B112", "B1G", 
"B1GM", "B1GM_XE", "B1GM_XI", "B1GM_XO", "B2G_B3G", "D1", "D2_M_D3", 
"D21_M_D31", "P3", "P3_P5", "P3_S13", "P31_S13", "P31_S14", "P31_S14_S15", 
"P31_S15", "P32_S13", "P5", "P51", "P52", "P52_P53", "P53", "P6", 
"P7"), class = "factor"), value = c(2556.8, 1506, NA, NA, NA, 
3056.1)), .Names = c("geo", "time", "indic_na", "value"), row.names = 7753:7758, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for such a clear question! Rare for a new user. I'd recommend `reshape2` over `reshape`.

```
GDP <- subset(GDP, (s_adj == "SWDA") & (unit == "MIO_EUR") & (time > "1989Q4"),
              select = c("geo", "time", "indic_na", "value"))
# Making your data match your example 

library(reshape2)    
GDP_wide <- dcast(GDP, geo + time ~ indic_na, value.var = "value")

> head(GDP_wide)
  geo    time    B11    B111   B112 ...
1  AT 1990 Q1  -64.3 -1407.1 1337.6 
2  AT 1990 Q2  -37.2 -1432.0 1450.3
3  AT 1990 Q3  -39.4 -1457.4 1544.2
4  AT 1990 Q4  -78.7 -1546.7 1592.7
5  AT 1991 Q1 -140.2 -1771.9 1583.0
6  AT 1991 Q2 -183.7 -1938.5 1568.3
```

Comment: Maybe a clear question , but to reproduce it you should install a package and load a data file....

Comment: Well yes, I'd prefer a `dput(head(GDP))` to installing some new package, but it *is* reproducible, and remarkably clear for someone's first question.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much! And thanks for the hint with the dput(head(...)), I'll keep that in mind :-)

Answer (score 2):

You may also try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
GDP %>%
filter(s_adj=="SWDA" & unit=="MIO_EUR" & time >"1989Q4") %>%
select(geo, time, indic_na, value) %>%
spread(indic_na, value) %>%
mutate(time=as.yearqtr(time)) %>%
head(2) 
   geo    time   B11    B111   B112     B1G    B1GM B1GM_XE B1GM_XI B1GM_XO
1  AT 1990 Q1 -64.3 -1407.1 1337.6 28198.6 31783.3  -132.0       0       0
2  AT 1990 Q2 -37.2 -1432.0 1450.3 28611.4 32215.3  -256.7       0       0
   B2G_B3G      D1 D21_M_D31 D2_M_D3      P3 P31_S13 P31_S14 P31_S14_S15 P31_S15
1 11123.2 16710.8    3592.1  3913.5 23858.2  3342.0 17493.5     17925.6   429.9
2 11304.7 16950.7    3613.1  3941.5 24150.3  3380.1 17696.8     18137.3   438.2
  P32_S13   P3_P5 P3_S13     P5    P51   P52 P52_P53  P53      P6      P7
1  2614.0 31963.5 5969.7 8105.3 7544.3 440.6   516.1 75.5 11640.6 11785.3
2  2632.1 32329.2 6020.1 8178.9 7652.9 394.7   472.2 77.5 11916.3 11851.2
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference, here's the base R `reshape` approach:

```
## Subsetting as per @Gregor's answer
GDP <- subset(GDP, (s_adj == "SWDA") & (unit == "MIO_EUR") & (time > "1989Q4"),
              select = c("geo", "time", "indic_na", "value"))

## The actual reshaping step
gdp_wide <- reshape(GDP, direction = "wide", 
                    idvar=c("geo", "time"), 
                    timevar="indic_na")

head(gdp_wide, 3)
#      geo    time value.B11 value.B111 value.B112 value.B1G value.B1GM
# 7753  AT 2014 Q1    2556.8     -352.6     4295.2   72065.1    79361.4
# 7754  BE 2014 Q1    1506.0         NA         NA   86513.0    96789.0
# 7755  BG 2014 Q1        NA         NA         NA    8496.6     9881.7
#      value.B1GM_XE value.B1GM_XI value.B1GM_XO value.B2G_B3G value.D1
# 7753           177            NA            NA       30409.6  40402.3
# 7754            NA            NA            NA       36251.0  50573.0
# 7755            NA            NA            NA        4475.7   4133.9
#      value.D21_M_D31 value.D2_M_D3 value.P3 value.P31_S13 value.P31_S14
# 7753          7351.4        8540.1  58941.2        9043.1       42602.2
# 7754         10276.0        9965.0  75733.0            NA       50434.0
# 7755          1370.1        1247.5   8099.9         879.7        6296.1
#      value.P31_S14_S15 value.P31_S15 value.P32_S13 value.P3_P5 value.P3_S13
# 7753           43838.4        1221.8        6153.4     75305.2      15154.2
# 7754           51499.0        1065.0            NA     95283.0      24234.0
# 7755            6338.8          40.7         895.6     10230.8       1790.3
#      value.P5 value.P51 value.P52 value.P52_P53 value.P53 value.P6 value.P7
# 7753  16364.0   16647.9    -281.3            68     349.3  46458.8  41903.8
# 7754  19550.0   19694.0    -144.0          -144       0.0  81501.0  79996.0
# 7755   2130.9    1975.9      72.0            72        NA   6850.2   7117.0
```

Here was your approach with a few comments that should help you with using `reshape`. However, now that there's `dcast.data.table`, `reshape` has started to feel quite slow.

```
reshape(data = GDP,            # This is correct
        direction = "long",    # Your data are already "long". You're going from
                               #   "long" to "wide", so set it to "wide".
        idvar = "geo",         # idvars are like the row stubs in the resulting 
                               #   data. You can have multiple idvars (use `c()`)
        timevar = "time",      # timevars are like the colnames or how you want 
                               #   to spread the data out in a wide form.
        varying = testvector)  # If you only have one value column, this argument
                               #   is rarely necessary. I generally set the 
                               #   "data" argument to just have the columns of 
                               #   interest so that I don't need to worry about
                               #   this argument or to use the `drop` argument.
```

Comment: I've change to data.table by now as well. Would also recommend that to any new user still reading this.