# Plotting and Linear Regression models with R

Tags: r, plot, lm

I am working a homework project for R, I have a CSV file that i need to import, so some analysis on and create a scatter plot and linear regression.

At one point my code has an error, and I am not sure why or where, I think it might be in this line:

```
x <- c("Name", "Washington")

CTD <- subset (Current_Data, grepl(paste(x, collapse = "|"), Current_Data$V1))
```

So i am new to R, this being the first class i've taken, I googled some and did find one thread on here that had some insight, but even using that code, i still get errors. ([Linear Regression Analysis of population data with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55787681/linear-regression-analysis-of-population-data-with-r))

in talking with others from my class and my professor i went another route, though i'm not sure which is better.

Here is the current code i am using.:

```
Current_Data<-read.csv("Statepop.csv",header=F,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Current_Data

x <- c("Name", "Washington")

CTD <- subset (Current_Data, grepl(paste(x, collapse = "|"), Current_Data$V1))

CTD

C_T_D <- t(CTD)

C_T_D

colnames(C_T_D) <- c("Year","Population")
```

Current_Data is perfect (though that is just reading the CSV)
but when i get to CTD is where i think something in broken.

CTD gives me this responce

```
    V1      V2      V3      V4      V5      V6      V7      V8      V9     V10
54 Washington 6742902 6821655 6892876 6962906 7052439 7163543 7294680 7425432 7535591
```

the problem here is it has not dropped the years, so when i go to take the row and make it to columns with the "t()" function (C_D_T)

i get this:

> C_T_D
>       54
>   V1  "Washington"
>   V2  "6742902"
>   V3  "6821655"
>   V4  "6892876"
>   V5  "6962906"
>   V6  "7052439"
>   V7  "7163543"
>   V8  "7294680"
>   V9  "7425432"
>   V10 "7535591"

since i've lost the years, the Colnames does not work and gives me this error:

> colnames(C_T_D) <- c("Year","Population")
>   Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
>     length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

EDIT: this is the out put from Current_Data.

> Current_Data
>                        V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6        V7        V8        V9       V10
>   1                  NAME      2010      2011      2012      2013      2014      2015      2016      2017      2018
>   2         United States 309326085 311580009 313874218 316057727 318386421 320742673 323071342 325147121 327167434
>   3      Northeast Region  55380645  55600532  55776729  55907823  56015864  56047587  56058789  56072676  56111079
>   4        Midwest Region  66974749  67152631  67336937  67564135  67752238  67869139  67996917  68156035  68308744
>   5          South Region 114867066 116039399 117271075 118393244 119657737 121037542 122401186 123598424 124753948
>   6           West Region  72103625  72787447  73489477  74192525  74960582  75788405  76614450  77319986  77993663
>   7               Alabama   4785448   4798834   4815564   4830460   4842481   4853160   4864745   4875120   4887871
>   8                Alaska    713906    722038    730399    737045    736307    737547    741504    739786    737438
>   9               Arizona   6407774   6473497   6556629   6634999   6733840   6833596   6945452   7048876   7171646
>   10             Arkansas   2921978   2940407   2952109   2959549   2967726   2978407   2990410   3002997   3013825
>   11           California  37320903  37641823  37960782  38280824  38625139  38953142  39209127  39399349  39557045
>   12             Colorado   5048281   5121771   5193721   5270482   5351218   5452107   5540921   5615902   5695564
>   13          Connecticut   3579125   3588023   3594395   3594915   3594783   3587509   3578674   3573880   3572665
>   14             Delaware    899595    907316    915188    923638    932596    941413    949216    957078    967171
>   15 District of Columbia    605085    619602    634725    650431    662513    675254    686575    695691    702455
>   16              Florida  18845785  19093352  19326230  19563166  19860330  20224249  20629982  20976812  21299325
>   17              Georgia   9711810   9801578   9901496   9973326  10069001  10181111  10304763  10413055  10519475
>   18               Hawaii   1363963   1379252   1394905   1408453   1414862   1422484   1428105   1424203   1420491
>   19                Idaho   1570773   1583828   1595441   1611530   1631479   1651523   1682930   1718904   1754208
>   20             Illinois  12840762  12867291  12884119  12898269  12888962  12864342  12826895  12786196  12741080
>   21              Indiana   6490436   6516045   6537640   6568367   6593533   6608296   6633344   6660082   6691878
>   22                 Iowa   3050767   3066054   3076097   3093078   3109504   3121460   3131785   3143637   3156145
>   23               Kansas   2858213   2869035   2885361   2893510   2900896   2909502   2911263   2910689   2911505
>   24             Kentucky   4348200   4369488   4386381   4404817   4414483   4425999   4438229   4453874   4468402
>   25            Louisiana   4544532   4575184   4600814   4624577   4644204   4664851   4678215   4670818   4659978
>   26                Maine   1327632   1328150   1327691   1328196   1330760   1328484   1331370   1335063   1338404
>   27             Maryland   5788642   5838991   5887072   5923704   5958165   5986717   6004692   6024891   6042718
>   28        Massachusetts   6566431   6613149   6663158   6713944   6763652   6795891   6826022   6863246   6902149
>   29             Michigan   9877535   9881521   9896930   9913349   9930589   9932573   9951890   9976447   9995915
>   30            Minnesota   5310843   5345668   5376550   5413693   5451522   5482503   5523409   5568155   5611179
>   31          Mississippi   2970536   2978470   2983767   2988797   2990623   2988693   2988298   2989663   2986530
>   32             Missouri   5995976   6009641   6024081   6040658   6056293   6071745   6087203   6108612   6126452
>   33              Montana    990722    997221   1003754   1013564   1021891   1030503   1040863   1053090   1062305
>   34             Nebraska   1829536   1840538   1853323   1865414   1879522   1891507   1905924   1917575   1929268
>   35               Nevada   2702464   2712799   2744566   2776972   2819012   2868666   2919772   2972405   3034392
>   36        New Hampshire   1316777   1319815   1323962   1326408   1333223   1336294   1342373   1349767   1356458
>   37           New Jersey   8799624   8827783   8845483   8858362   8866780   8870869   8874516   8888543   8908520
>   38           New Mexico   2064588   2080395   2087549   2092792   2090342   2090211   2092789   2093395   2095428
>   39             New York  19400080  19498514  19574549  19628043  19656330  19661411  19641589  19590719  19542209
>   40       North Carolina   9574293   9656754   9749123   9843599   9933944  10033079  10156679  10270800  10383620
>   41         North Dakota    674710    685136    701116    721999    737382    754022    754353    755176    760077
>   42                 Ohio  11539327  11543463  11548369  11576576  11602973  11617850  11635003  11664129  11689442
>   43             Oklahoma   3759632   3787821   3818600   3853205   3878367   3909831   3926769   3932640   3943079
>   44               Oregon   3837532   3871728   3899118   3922908   3964106   4016918   4091404   4146592   4190713
>   45         Pennsylvania  12711158  12744583  12766827  12776621  12789101  12785759  12783538  12790447  12807060
>   46         Rhode Island   1053938   1053536   1054601   1055122   1056017   1056173   1057063   1056486   1057315
>   47       South Carolina   4635656   4671422   4717112   4764153   4823793   4892253   4958235   5021219   5084127
>   48         South Dakota    816165    823484    833496    842270    849088    853933    862890    873286    882235
>   49            Tennessee   6355301   6397410   6451281   6493432   6540826   6590808   6645011   6708794   6770010
>   50                Texas  25242679  25646227  26089620  26489464  26977142  27486814  27937492  28322717  28701845
>   51                 Utah   2775334   2814216   2853467   2897927   2937399   2982497   3042613   3103118   3161105
>   52              Vermont    625880    626979    626063    626212    625218    625197    623644    624525    626299
>   53             Virginia   8023680   8100469   8185229   8253053   8312076   8362907   8410946   8465207   8517685
>   54           Washington   6742902   6821655   6892876   6962906   7052439   7163543   7294680   7425432   7535591
>   55        West Virginia   1854214   1856074   1856764   1853873   1849467   1841996   1830929   1817048   1805832
>   56            Wisconsin   5690479   5704755   5719855   5736952   5751974   5761406   5772958   5792051   5813568
>   57              Wyoming    564483    567224    576270    582123    582548    585668    584290    578934    577737
>   58          Puerto Rico   3721525   3678732   3634488   3593077   3534874   3473166   3406495   3325001   3195153

Comment: CTD is in rows, not columns, CTD should have the years in row 1 and the population est. in row 2. the t() is to make them in to columns so i have years in column1 and population est. in column 2

Comment: @DaveT  the dput you asked for produced this error:

> dput(head(Current_Data[, c("Name", "Washington")], 20))
Error in `[.data.frame`(Current_Data, , c("Name", "Washington")) : 
  undefined columns selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The t() function is creating a matrix with dimensions greater than 2. The error is saying that you are only giving the matrix two column names, but the matrix array needs more than two.

Is there a reason you are doing `header = F`? If not, then the following may work:

```
Current_Data <- read.csv("nst-est2018-alldata.csv", header=T,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

head(Current_Data)

x <- c("Name", "Washington")

CTD <- subset(Current_Data, grepl(paste(x, collapse = "|"), Current_Data$NAME))

CTD

# the data are in wide format, but you seem to want them in long format
C_T_D <- stack(CTD)[-1,]

C_T_D

# looks like our columns are switched
C_T_D2 <- C_T_D[,c(2,1)]

colnames(C_T_D2) <- c("Year","Population")

#to make the data easier to work with
C_T_D2$Year <- as.numeric(str_extract_all(C_T_D2$Year, "[0-9]+"))
C_T_D2$Population <- as.numeric(C_T_D2$Population)
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the data to make your question reproducible? Alternatively, can you show what the data look like so we can better understand the issue?

Comment: https://www.census.gov/data/tables/time-series/demo/popest/2010s-national-total.html#par_textimage

I then downloaded the NST-EST2018-alldata.csv

I did do some editing to the CSV file, I removed the extra information on there I did not need, I removed columns A through D, F and G (original columns) and then everything after the 2018 POP Estimate.

Comment: this is a sample output from Current_Data:

                     V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6        V7        V8        V9       V10
1                  NAME      2010      2011      2012      2013      2014      2015      2016      2017      2018
2         United States 309326085 311580009 313874218 316057727 318386421 320742673 323071342 325147121 327167434
.
.
.
7               Alabama   4785448   4798834   4815564   4830460   4842481   4853160   4864745   4875120   4887871

Comment: Now, I am trying to work with the data for Washington, but I cants paste that much in comments

Comment: Made a few updates to the above code. Let me know if that works. Good luck!